# Get Div Children in Coded Ui

Tags: html, coded-ui-tests

I have a parent Div and child Div like below.

```
 --ParentDiv
     --ChildDiv!
```

[Parent and Child divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko7e3.png)

I know the `ParentDiv` Id (which is static). I want to know the `ChildDiv` Id which keeps changing. How to do this?

I tried below matching the Class. But it says.. "The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties."

```
HtmlControl childDiv = parentDiv.GetChildren()[0].Find<HtmlControl>(new { Class = "cmd-datatable" });
string id = parentLvl2.GetProperty("Id").ToString();
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: 'parentDiv.GetChildren()[0]' should be the div itself. What does Find<T> do? It doesn't look like a standard UITestControl method to me.

Answer (score 0):

The following should return the id of the first child.

```
HtmlDiv parent = new HtmlDiv(browser);
parent.SearchProperties["id"] = "thisDivsID";
string childID = parent.GetChildren()[0].GetProperty("ID").ToString();
```

You could also wrap the whole thing in a foreach loop:

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>();
foreach(UITestControl child in parent.GetChildren())
{
    ids.Add(child.GetProperty("ID").ToString();
}
```